# If a ScrollView is the parent, it doesn't show a TableLayout into a RelativeLayout(Android)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-tablelayout, android-scrollview

I have this xml file:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/conteiner_2"
            android:layout_width="500px"
            android:layout_height="500px"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_2">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
 </ScrollView>
```

And I am trying to create a `TableLayout` which if I delete the `ScrollViews` it appears, but when I let it like before the `TableLayout` isn't show.
This is my code:

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramsTable = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams paramsRow = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,1.0f);
    TableRow.LayoutParams paramsCol = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1.0f);
    for(int row = 0 ; row < rows ; row++){
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        row.setLayoutParams(paramsRow);

        for(int col = 0 ; col < column ; col++){
            TextView text = new TextView(this);
            text.setLayoutParams(paramsCol);
            text.setText(row + "-" + col);
            row.addView(text);
        }
        table.addView(row);
    }

    tabla.setLayoutParams(paramsTable);
    conteiner.addView(table);
```

Sorry for my poor English, I hope I made myself understood.

<<< EDIT >>>
I have to put another layout inside the `RelativeLayout`, and it works.

Comment: Why do you want horizontalscrollview within scrollview?

Comment: Because I need a horizontal and vertical scrolling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put another layout inside the `RelativeLayout`, and it works.